# CLLocationManager code for ios8 isn't working in ios7

Tags: ios7, gps, ios8, cllocationmanager

Previously I used a simple code(which I not posting here) for gps tracking, which works perfectly fine on iPhone 4. Currently I'm using the following code in viewcontroller.m for getting current gps location:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self CurrentLocationIdentifier];
}

-(void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
{
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; 
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    current = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:current completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!(error))
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
             NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
             NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
             NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
             NSString *Area = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.locality];
             NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.country];
             NSString *CountryArea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Area,Country];
             NSLog(@"Address: %@", Address);
             NSLog(@"CountryArea: %@",CountryArea);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error);
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Not Detected\n");
         }

     }];
}
```

I Used this [link](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/) to support gps tracking for iPhone 6.This code fetches current gps location on **iPhone 6 and iPhone 4S** but not in **iPhone 5S and iPhone 6 Plus**.I'm wondering why this is happening?

Comment: don't call the both requestWhenInUseAuthorization and requestAlwaysAuthorization - in the same time; choose only one!

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @simply_me : Yes, don't use `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`
        `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` at the same time.